# How can I get content out of Google Maps MVCArray?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I'm working with [google.maps.polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).  The library uses a [google.maps.MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) element to store the vertices of the polygon where each vertex contains a latitude and longitude variable.  So I'm able to create fancy polygons on the fly using user mouse clicks.

```
var listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(e) {
    var latLng = e.latLng;
    var myMvcArray = new google.maps.MVCArray();
    myMvcArray.push(latLng); // First Point
    var myPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        paths: myMvcArray, // one time registration reqd only
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.10,
        editable: true,
        draggable: false,
        clickable: true
    });
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);

    var listener2 = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        latLng = e.latLng;
        myMvcArray.push(latLng);
        console.log(myMvcArray.getArray());
    });
});
```

My problem is, that console log result is incomprehensible. I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure out how to get clean data from myMvcArray.  I need to use the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turns out the trick is this:

```
console.log(myMvcArray.getArray()[0].lat(), myMvcArray.getArray()[0].lng() );
```

Which returns:  `XX.XX2157415679654 -XXX.XX782657623291`

A For/Each loop will also work.

```
myMvcArray.getArray().forEach(function(value, index, array_x) {
    console.log(" index: " + index + "    value: " + value);
})
```

Which returns:

```
index: 0    value: (XX.XX2157415679654, -XXX.XX782657623291)
index: 1    value: (XX.XX209255908967, -XXX.XX77514743805)
```

Info offered in case anybody else has issues here.  Note, too, the code above works pretty well for letting users define a google.maps.polygon on a map easily.

Comment: MVCArray has it's own forEach method as well, so calling getArray() is unnecessary in most use cases: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#MVCArray.forEach

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`

So your code would be

`console.log(JSON.stringify(myMvcArray.getArray()))`

This works because stringify calls the methods on the MVCArray to get the contents whereas log doesn't.